# Resize TextArea horizontally and vertically

Tags: java, resize, textarea, javafx

I created a basic layout in JavaFX. How can I get the `TextArea` on the bottom left to resize to use the complete available whitespace? For now it just resizes horizontally but not vertically.

The code:

```
public VBox addVBoxLeft() {

    VBox vBoxLeft = new VBox();
    vBoxLeft.setSpacing(10);
    vBoxLeft.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    //Content vBoxLeft
    Text titleGamesAvailable = new Text("Games available:");
    titleGamesAvailable.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
    TextArea chatHistory = new TextArea();
    chatHistory.setText("...");
    chatHistory.setEditable(false);
    chatHistory.setWrapText(true);
    chatHistory.setPrefColumnCount(2);

    vBoxLeft.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    vBoxLeft.getChildren().addAll(titleGamesAvailable, availableGamesList(),chatHistory);

    return vBoxLeft;
}

private ListView<String> availableGamesList() {
    this.availableGamesListView = new ListView<String>();
    availableGamesListView.setItems(gamelist);
    return availableGamesListView;
}

public VBox addVBoxRight() {
    VBox vboxRight = new VBox();
    vboxRight.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    vboxRight.setSpacing(8);

    Text title = new Text("Users online:");
    title.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 14));

    this.userOnlineListView = new ListView<String>();
    this.userlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    userOnlineListView.setItems(userlist);
    VBox.setVgrow(userOnlineListView, Priority.ALWAYS);
    vboxRight.getChildren().addAll(title, userOnlineListView);

    return vboxRight;
}

private void _showView() {
    this.primaryStage = new Stage();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Carcassonne");

    // Als Grundlayout dient Borderpane
    BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    border.setPrefSize(1024, 768);

    // HBox hbox = addHBox();
    border.setTop(addHBoxTop());
    border.setCenter(addVBoxLeft());
    border.setRight(addVBoxRight());


    Scene scene = new Scene(border);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Lobby");
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(800);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AnchorPane and set the appropriate constraints to stretch the TextArea the way you want

Comment: "Use AnchorPane." Any chance you could elaborate with a code example?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. i used a borderpane with just VBoxes instead and ONLY the TOP list has a VGow.